# "ERROR: Failed building wheel for multidict" on M1 Mac

Tags: pycharm, twilio, homebrew, apple-m1

I encountered an error while installing the 'twilio' package on PyCharm Community Edition. Additionally, I discovered some supplementary errors when executing 'pip install twilio' as suggested.

[ERROR: Failed building wheel for multidict](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDgQx.png)

[Error while install by clicking redline on code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNV98.png)

```
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Building wheel for frozenlist (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [37 lines of output]
```

[error shows when I installing by 'pip install twilio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f99QE.png)

I've updated Homebrew, Rosetta 2, and PIP, but unfortunately, none of these actions resolved the issue. If anyone notices anything I might have overlooked, please share your insights.

PyCharm 2023.2.5 (Community Edition)
wheel 0.38.4
pip 23.3.1

**What I were expecting?**
I was expecting to code using 'twilio' package

Comment: ERROR: Failed building wheel for multidict
Failed to build multidict
ERROR: Could not build wheels for multidict, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects